# Connecting AWS IoT Core and Cognito for Data Sending and Authorization

Tags: python, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-iot-core, aws-iam-policy

I am sending data to AWS IOT Core with MQTT. I used to use X.509 certificate file to connect to AWS IoT Core MQTT but now I want to use Cognito instead of this certificate. I want users in Cognito to only send user1 to topic1 and user2 to topic2. How can I set this? How do I connect it core to Cognito? Should I create a policy in IAM or an Iot policy? How can I write the required policy for this?

In this case, how is write the python code that I send the data to iot core using Cognito? The previous code is as follows (code when I use iot X.509 certificate file);

```
import json
import random
import AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib as AWSIoTPyMQTT

# AWSIoTMQTTClient connection configuration
ENDPOINT = "iot-endpoint"
PATH_TO_CERT = "certificate.pem.crt"
PATH_TO_KEY = "private.pem.key"
PATH_TO_ROOT = "AmazonRootCA1.pem"
CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
PORT = 8883
TOPIC = test/topic1
myAWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTPyMQTT.AWSIoTMQTTClient(CLIENT_ID)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(ENDPOINT, PORT)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureCredentials(PATH_TO_ROOT, PATH_TO_KEY, PATH_TO_CERT)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect()
print('Begin Publish')

while True:
   random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
   data = {'id': 1, 'value': random_number}
    # Publish to AWS
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(TOPIC, json.dumps(data), 1)
    print(f"Published:  {json.dumps(data)} to the topic:  {TOPIC}")

print('Publish End')
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.disconnect()
```

How am I supposed to write the code when I use Cognito? Which python library can I use?

Can you help me with this?